# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def update_url(self): 
    data = self.env['wizard.seniat.url'].read()
    url_obj = self._get_url()
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': data['url1'],
         'url_seniat': data['url2'],
         'url_seniat2': data['url3']})
    return {}
```

This is a button, every time I click it, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 77, in update_url
{'name': data['url1'],
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

This is a module I'm migrating from v8 to v10 community.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the original method on old API:

```
def update_url(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    data = self.pool.get('wizard.seniat.url').read(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': data['url1'],
         'url_seniat': data['url2'],
         'url_seniat2': data['url3']})
    return {}
```

Comment: What do you want to hear? `data` is a list which you cannot index into with strings.

Comment: This should update those fields, I'm not sure how to migrate that, I'm not fond into new api

Comment: I'm going to add the original method on old api

Comment: Just edited my question, thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using read() is a bad practice. read() is used for web-services calls
but in your own method calls you should always use browse(). Not only,
it allows s a better quality of the code, but it’s also better for the
performance.

– read() calls name_get() for many2one fields producing extra SQL queries
you probably don’t need.
– browse() is optimized for prefetching and auto-load of fields.

Here you should try:

```
@api.multi
def update_url(self): 
data = self.env['wizard.seniat.url'].read()[0]
url_obj = self._get_url()
url_obj.write(
    {'name': data and data['url1'],
     'url_seniat': data and data['url2'],
     'url_seniat2': data and data['url3']})
return {}
```

You can refer odoo 10 basic ORM [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html)